# How to conform text to a surface using a displacement map in Python?

Tags: python, imagemagick, image-manipulation, image-editing, python-fu

I am working on a project where I need to programmatically add a text to an image such that the text conforms to the surface so that it looks much more real-life.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huvysaySBrw

[image: Displaced text over image]

I am fairly new when it comes to programmatic image editing. I have gone through quite a bit of documentation of ImageMagick and similar libraries. But didn't find anything that might help me so far.

Comment: There is  a "Displace map" in Gimp that you can use from a Gimp python plugin (using the Gimp UI) or from a Python script in CLI mode. But this "displace map" is another image so it all depends how you produce that one.

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Moon, did you manage to make it work ? :)

Comment: Hello Moon, have you found any solution ?

Comment: Hi @Moon, I'm also facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @Moon. could you find any programmatic solution?